# Get time out message when trying to do vagrant up on Windows 10 - but no errors

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, git-bash, homestead

I get this error message when I try to vagrant up in my git-bash.

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead-7
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

The problem is that i do not get any errors and if I go into my Virtualbox GUI, the VM is running!

Anybody who have experienced the same thing a have a solution.

It is on windows 10, with the latest virtualbox and vagrant.

I have just installed it on my laptop at home and i works fine, but at work on a work domain it won't, so can't really see what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me when I was setting up a Windows box. So, I would check if Virtualization is enabled in BIOS. If it is disabled, enable it. Try to boot again.

Comment: NO NO NO!! I'm stupid! I have read this suggestions a lot of times, but instead of going into BIOS to check I used this http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/processor-utilities-and-programs/intel-processor-identification-utility.html program to check, and it said yes. So I didn't thougt it was that problem, but after your suggestion again, I did the BIOS thing and found out that it was disabled!! Stupid lazy me, this just cost me 5 hours of hair pulling and 2 clean windows install:-D Thanks again!