# vagrant 'Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot' in windows 10

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have recently updated my windows10  and tried to run the virtual machine but it kept me thrownig the same error number of times 'Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot', I have tried all the possible ways, enabling gui, increasing the timeout value and even updated the vagrant and virtual box

```
C:\Users\tmsfi\fullstack-nanodegree-vm\vagrant>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04-i386' is up to date...
==> default: There was a problem while downloading the metadata for your box
==> default: to check for updates. This is not an error, since it is usually 
due
==> default: to temporary network problems. This is just a warning. The 
problem
==> default: encountered was:
==> default:
==> default: Could not resolve host: vagrantcloud.com
==> default:
==> default: If you want to check for box updates, verify your network 
connection
==> default: is valid and try again.
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 8000 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 8080 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 5000 (guest) => 5000 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

C:\Users\tmsfi\fullstack-nanodegree-vm\vagrant>vagrant ssh
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Please help me to solve this issue , Thanks in advance
Meghana

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get time out message when trying to do vagrant up on Windows 10 - but no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569157/get-time-out-message-when-trying-to-do-vagrant-up-on-windows-10-but-no-errors)

Comment: Thanks @DanilaSmirnov

Answer (score 4):

I have figured it out, we will face this issue because of the virtualization is disabled in our system.To check whether it is enabled or disabled go to your

```
Taskmanager-->Performance
```

check whether Virtualization is enabled or disabled, if disabled then enable it This happens when our windows is updated to latest version we need to enable the virtualization in BIOS settings, to do this go to

```
setting-->Update&Security-->Recovery-->Advance startup-->click(restart now)
```

after restarting it provides with few options then click on

```
Troubleshoot-->Advanced options-->Select UEFI Firmware Settings-->Click 
Restart.
```

Your system will restart and take you to the BIOS. Now enable your Intel Virtual technology and save it and restart your system.

Refer to this [How to change BIOS settings in windows](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/access-bios-windows-10)

Comment: Also should make sure HyperV is turned off, I overlooked this in the docs and wasted 2 days fixing this: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation#windows-virtualbox-and-hyper-v